# Can this ratio be an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that the number
$$\frac{b^3+1}{ab-1}$$
is never an integer for positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\geq 6$ and $a\geq b$?

Comment: It could be.  What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: I just found that there are some cases where this ratio is an integer (such as $a=5$ and $b=3$), but I have no idea how to handle the general issue.

Comment: Your constraint on a says it must be bigger than 6,in your example a is 5.

Comment: I suggest that the first thing to do is factor where possible: $b^3+1=(b+1)\cdot (b^2-b+1)$.  Then it seems clear that any solutions must depend on having some factors of $ab-1$ present in each portion of the factors of $b^3+1$.  Just some random thoughts...

Comment: IMO 1994 Q4 asks to solve the above equation in integers. Note that all solutions have $a \lt 6$ 
 http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln944.html

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Thanks a lot!! Now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach:

By definition you can say that $b^2+{2 \over b} \ge a \ge b$ because $(b^2+{2 \over b})b-1 = b^3+1$ . But because  ${2 \over b}$ is only an integer for $b=1$ or $b=2$ your interval for $a$ is effectively $[b, b^2]$ . This means you can write $a=b\cdot b^x$ with $0 \le x \le 1$ or $a=b \sqrt[y]{b}$ with $y = {1 \over x}$ . If you combine this with  the original term you get ${b^3+1 \over b^2 \sqrt[y]{b}-1}=n, \quad n \in N \quad \Rightarrow b^3+(1+n) = n b^2 \sqrt[y]{b}$ . This concludes that if you can show that for some $b $ if  $n\sqrt[y]{b} \in N$ , $b^2\sqrt[y]{b} \in N$ and $nb^2\sqrt[y]{b} \in N$ lead to a contradiction  then for this $b$ ${b^3+1 \over ab-1}$  is not an integer for every $a$.

Comment: How does this approach deal with the case $a=5,b=3$? That is, where are you using $a\geq 6$?

Comment: If the case is $a=5,b=3$ then $n=2$ (the solution) and $\sqrt[{1 \over \log_3 {5 \over 3}}]{3}3^2 \in N$ so that  $\sqrt[{1 \over \log_3 {5 \over 3}}]{3}3^2*2 = 3^3+1+2=30$ . Basically this approach replaces $a \in N$ for another variable $y \ge 1$ as $sqrt[y]{b} = {a \over b}$.